# android testing mockup components

Tags: android, testing

I would like to make some automatic UI tests for my Android application using recomended approach ( http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html ). My activity  fetches data from server and after getting response it modifies some UI elements. I want to check whether UI is modified properly but I also want to test this issue without connecting to server. I thought about providing mock component instead of object which connects to server on behalf of activity. But how could I in my test cases tell acivity to replace original object with mock object? Do you know any good approches?

I thought about putting a special flag in Intent using setActivityIntent (indicating that mock object should be used) before calling getActivity in my ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 instance.
But this approach requires adding some if statements in application code what makes code less clear and more complicated.

Do you have any better suggestions? Thanks in advance.